# ng-animate when ng-view is updated through route

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I try to animate the change of a ng-view div in AngularJS.

So my div inside my index.html file looks like:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

I have another html-file (view1.html) with just divs inside.

My app.js with the routing looks like:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/sites/:templateID',
    {
        controller: 'simpleController',
        templateUrl:'templates/question.html'
    })
});
```

I am changing the path with a click on a button, and call this:

```
$location.path("/sites/" + nextID);
```

The URL changes of the site, and only the ng-view-div gets updated. But when i am applying a ng-animation to it:

```
<div class="content" data-ng-view ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}"></div>
```

It doesn't work. I included AngularJS 1.2.5, the animate-js file inside my index.html and also my CSS:

```
.animate-enter, .animate-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all 2s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 2s ease;
  -o-transition:all 2s ease;
  transition:all 2s ease;
}

.animate-enter {
    left: -100%;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}

.animate-leave {
    left: 0;
}

.animate-leave.animate-leave-active {
    left: 100%;
}
```

**Is there a way to animate the ng-view change through route-(URL)-changing?**

Comment: What if you add 'position: absolute' or relative to the .animate-enter, .animate-leave css class. Can you setup a plunker?

Comment: As of AngularJS 1.2 the `ng-animate` directive is no longer used and you'll need to change your css to follow the instructions on [this page](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html). I'll post an example as an answer shortly

Comment: Actually the problem is that angular animations are not run on page-load. So after your route has changed and new view is rendered animations won't run for it on first load.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few changes to the CSS rules with Angular Animation 1.2+. `ng-animate` directive is no longer used so AngularJS now changes the class of the element based on events, such as `hide`, `show`, etc.

You can define these like so in your CSS:

```
.toggle {
    -webkit-transition: all 0 cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    -moz-transition: all 0 cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    -ms-transition: all 0 cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    -o-transition: all 0 cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    transition: all 0 cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    /* easeOutQuad */
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    /* easeOutQuad */
}

.toggle.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duration: 250ms;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
}

.toggle.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.toggle.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: 250ms;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
}

.toggle.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle.ng-hide-add {
    transition-duration: 250ms;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
    opacity: 1;
}

.toggle.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle.ng-hide-remove {
    transition-duration: 250ms;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

That way when you have your HTML element you really only have to define the `class="toggle"` for example. When your app runs Angular will append the classes appropriately.

[Here is a good resource for different animation techniques by Augus](http://augus.github.io/ngAnimate/)

[And here is a break down of the changes in AngularJS Animations](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html)

Comment: Thank's very much, but still, doesn't work... looks like Angular cannot handle animation when i am changing the url.

Comment: Very interesting, I just applied an animation to my route change and it didn't work either, even though I have animations throughout my app. I will have to look into this more. I am, however, using [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead of Angular's routing, don't know if that conflicts.

Comment: If you open up your developers console in your browser, inspect the div with the routing and watch it when the route is changed, do you see anything change in the class of that div by chance?

Comment: Mine was due to `ui-router` which I found a branch that supports 1.2+, if this is what you are using than let me know. Unfortunately I don't have the time to convert all of my routes to `ngRoute` to test for you, if you are able to make a fiddle than let me know and I'll take a look.

Comment: Asok - Which branch was that?

Comment: @jul I am currently using the latest `ui-router` Version 0.2.10, but it should be working since Version 0.2.8. [Here is where I found the branch (The branch no longer exists)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/320). And [here is the minified 0.2.10](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js)

Comment: @Asok cheers. I'm still having problems with that version unfortunately. I have a ng-include bound to a scope variable which changes with the ui route state, and the ng-leave transition never fires. Works fine if I update the scope variable through e.g a ng-click. Maybe I'll post it as as separate so question.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. The question was that there is a problem specifically on route change.

Comment: @ivanp The OP was using a directive that was either deprecated or no longer included in the AngularJS framework. I can't troubleshoot an issue when I know there is an issue preventing me to do so. If you follow the comments in the Q thread then you'll see that I was helping the OP understand the changes in AngularJS animations. From there we could troubleshoot. When I came back the answer was marked as accepted. I can't control that. If you know the answer, than feel free to post and contact the OP to mark yours as accepted.

Answer (score 19):

`ng-view` can work with animation. In fact there is official example of it. Check out this [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive%3angView).

Also remember that you also need to declare `ngAnimate` dependency for it to work:

```
var app = angular.module('App', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate'
]);
```

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="question" ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Class `.question` defines CSS animation:

```
.question.ng-enter,
.question.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

#### Your modified demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BIjvbv6Ax1uardKP1Qoq?p=preview).

---

#### Mini-project

I also created a little project demonstrating different `ngView` animations. Check it out this **[page](http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app)**.

Comment: Is using Fixed layout ... no option

Answer (score 6):

In 1.2+ you no longer need the directive, the css notation has changed aswell.

The 1.2.5 way of doing it is as follows:

Give your View a class:

```
<div data-ng-view class="mainview-animation"></div>
```

Add the following dependency:

```
/**
 * Main Application & Dependencies
 * @type {*}
 */
var mainApp = angular.module('app', [
    // Angular modules
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate'
]);
```

Then add the following CSS:

```
/*
 The animate class is apart of the element and the ng-enter class
 is attached to the element once the enter animation event is triggered
*/
.mainview-animation.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: .3s linear all; /* Safari/Chrome */
  -moz-transition: .3s linear all; /* Firefox */
  -o-transition: .3s linear all; /* Opera */
  transition: .3s linear all; /* IE10+ and Future Browsers */
}

/**
 * Pre animation -> enter
 */
.mainview-animation.ng-enter{
  /* The animation preparation code */
  opacity: 0;
}

/**
 * Post animation -> enter
 */
.mainview-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active { 
  /* The animation code itself */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: This example is working... @gruberb check your Angular version.

Comment: I have the latest of both angular and nganimate. I cannot get ngview to take the transitional classes. It simply doesn't work i have nothing to troubleshoot

Comment: I was having a similar problem, and this answer helped me solve it. Basically, I needed to set the animation class on the same element as ng-view is - instead of what's inside it. It's ng-view that's doing the animiation - not the content inside it, so angular won't let you do animation if you try to do it on element inside ng-view.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the accepted answer it is necessary to either define position: absolute or display: block to .ng-enter and .ng-leave. I struggled with this for a while when trying to fade in ng-view on route change and didn't want to use absolute positioning. Example without browser prefixes for transition:

```
//add animate class to ng-view

//css
.animate.ng-leave, .animate.ng-enter { 
    transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.1, 0.25, 1) all;
}
.animate.ng-enter, .animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
}
.animate.ng-leave, .animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

For my specific situation I removed the transition from ng-leave so there wouldn't be overlap of elements which would cause one to be pushed down due to block display.